# Make sure I don't jump any blocks

Tags: ethereumjs, blocks

I'm making a simple program to track transactions in and out of an address, I have a function that gets the latest block and then I run it consecutively.

When I run the function sometimes the block I try to read is null, and some other times when I encounter a block full of transactions, the function takes more time to execute and I end up skipping a block.

How can I be sure the block number I'm checking is always <= of the latest block?

Is there any risk that I might scan an uncle block instead?

Here is my code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const PROJECT_ID = 'myprojectid'

// Connect to the node
const web3 = new Web3( Web3.givenProvider || `wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/${PROJECT_ID}`)
const eth = web3.eth

async function listenToBlocks(addressToWatch){
    // Get the latest block and the transactions 
    lastBlock = await eth.getBlock('latest','true')
   //Do stuff with the transactions here
}

const addressToWatch = 'myaddress'

const callback = async () => {
        eth.getBlockNumber().then(result => console.log(`Searching block: ${result}`))
        await listenToBlocks(network,addressToWatch)
        console.log('-'.repeat(30));
        setTimeout(callback,15000)
    }

setTimeout(callback,15000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a proof of work blockchain like Ethereum it is always possible for chain reorganization. The longer you wait the less likely a block will change.

It is very common for user wallets to use 12 blocks for transaction confirmation.

Exchanges often have longer waits, ie something like 24 or more.